# Scheduled build with C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, tfs, build, scheduled-tasks

I use visual studio 2008, and I would like to know if it is possible to run scheduled build on it.

Indeed, I have several projects I work on, and every time I change one, it may impact the other.

I would like to run, every night, a batch build on all my projects, so when I come in the morning I can see what compiled (and what did not compile as well).

Is there a way to schedule such a task in visual studio ?

**EDIT:** 
I probably should have mentioned that I needed a light weight solution, so the TFS and other are a bit to complicated to put in place for me. 
A simple scheduled task can do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both @Rup and @Nawaz have the best solutions.  If you're looking for something really low-tech, though, you could consider simply creating a windows task that does a command-line build of your code on a nightly basis.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to set up a continuous integration server, e.g. [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET), [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), etc. There's endless debates here about which is the best one. These can be configured to take your source from your source control and build it as scheduled jobs. Obviously if you're using TFS for source control then you can use TFS to do this as in [Nawaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613768/scheduled-build-with-c-in-visual-studio/4613788#4613788).

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need TFS. [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server)

See this: [How To: Set Up a Scheduled Build in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668975.aspx)

Comment: Though I'm a big fan of TFS, you don't *need* TFS.  As @Rup mentions above, there are lots of solutions for CI builds.

Comment: @Robaticus : I didn't say there are not. I just said there is this solution provided Microsoft itself. After all, the questioner is already using Microsoft Visual Studio.